# Dropbox selective syncing - pattern matching?

Tags: dropbox

I'm using Dropbox on daily basis and put my programming projects in there.
It works great, but once I got many projects my `/node_modules` dir's are putting 
a struggle on Dropbox. It's syncing process starts to be slow and it eats up CPU time.

Is there any way to do a selective sync based on directory name or a mask pattern?
Would be nice to have to a `.gitignore` equivalent to configure.

Any 3rd party software for that task?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to selectively sync but I don't believe it has any advanced rules like you're describing:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/175/en

Comment: Thanks Karl, but that I already read. I look for a more controllable way of syncing ;)

Answer (score 0):

2 way to resolve this problem:

1. You can put `node_modules` upper then project directory in files tree. For example:
   Project dir: `c:/prj/myProjWrapper/myProj`

   In the `c:/prj/myProjWrapper` put `package.json` and make `npm install` here, NodeJS recursively will find it.
2. Win and Linux only, not for Mac! In project dir create `.ds_store` folder (it is not sync by dropbox). Put `package.json` in to it and do `npm install`. You must set `NODE_PATH=./.ds_store/node_modules;.` when starting NodeJS